`BigInt` implementation in C++23
Cooked this up in 3 days because I was bored and thought this would be an interesting project to work on. This BigInt implementation does what you'd expect it to do, you can use it like an ordinary integer type except there's no limit to how big the number can be (well, technically, there is a limit which is 2 ^ PTRDIFF_MAX, but that's several exbiytes of data on a 64-bit machine so good luck reaching that).
It uses a sign-magnitude representation for the number, the sign being stored as a boolean value and the magnitude being stored as a std::deque of chunks. Each chunk is an integer of type std::uint_fast32_t. Optimization for small numbers is planned in the future but not implemented yet.
The implementation spans 4 files:

bigint.hpp: Contains the declarations and some template functions.
bigint.cpp: Contains most of the implementation minus the logic for handling strings.
string_parser.cpp: Contains the logic for string parsing and converting strings to BigInt and vice-versa.
utils.hpp: Contains some useful utilities used throughout the project.

The whole project is available on https://github.com/famiu/BigInt, it also contains tests for the library if you're interested in that.
The code (minus the tests) is also included below for convenience:
include/bigint.hpp:
#pragma once

#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>
#include <format>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#include "utils.hpp"

namespace BI
{
class BigInt
{
public:
    using ChunkType = std::uint_fast32_t;
    using DataType = std::deque<ChunkType>;

    BigInt();
    BigInt(BigInt const &rhs) = default;
    BigInt(BigInt &&rhs) noexcept = default;

    explicit BigInt(std::integral auto const &num) noexcept : negative{num < 0}
    {
        auto const num_unsigned = detail::to_unsigned(negative ? -num : num);
        auto const num_size = sizeof(num_unsigned) * 8;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < num_size; i += chunk_bits) {
            chunks.push_back(static_cast<ChunkType>((num_unsigned >> i) & chunk_max));
        }

        // Remove leading zeroes.
        remove_leading_zeroes();
    }

    explicit BigInt(std::string_view num);
    ~BigInt() = default;

    auto operator=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt & = default;
    auto operator=(BigInt &&rhs) noexcept -> BigInt & = default;

    auto operator+() const noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator-() const noexcept -> BigInt;

    auto operator+(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator-(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator*(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator/(BigInt const &rhs) const -> BigInt;
    auto operator%(BigInt const &rhs) const -> BigInt;

    auto operator<<(size_t rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator>>(size_t rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;

    auto operator+=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator-=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator*=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator/=(BigInt const &rhs) -> BigInt &;
    auto operator%=(BigInt const &rhs) -> BigInt &;

    auto operator<<=(size_t rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator>>=(size_t rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &;

    auto operator++() noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator--() noexcept -> BigInt &;
    auto operator++(int) noexcept -> BigInt;
    auto operator--(int) noexcept -> BigInt;

    auto operator<=>(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> std::strong_ordering;
    auto operator==(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> bool;

    auto operator<=>(std::integral auto const &rhs) const noexcept -> std::strong_ordering
    {
        try {
            return static_cast<decltype(rhs)>(*this) <=> rhs;
        } catch (std::overflow_error const &) {
            return negative ? std::strong_ordering::less : std::strong_ordering::greater;
        }
    }

    auto operator==(std::integral auto const &rhs) const noexcept -> bool
    {
        return (*this <=> rhs) == std::strong_ordering::equal;
    }

    template<std::integral T>
    explicit operator T() const
    {
        using UnsignedT = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;

        constexpr auto is_signed = std::is_signed_v<T>;
        size_t const num_bits = this->bit_count();

        // Unsigned types cannot store negative numbers.
        if (negative && !is_signed) {
            throw std::underflow_error(std::format("Number can't fit in unsigned type '{}'", detail::type_name<T>()));
        }
        // Signed types can store 1 less bit than their signed counterpart.
        if (num_bits > (sizeof(T) * 8) - static_cast<size_t>(is_signed)) {
            throw std::overflow_error(  // clang-format off
                    std::format("Number is too large to be converted to type '{}'", detail::type_name<T>())
            );  // clang-format on
        }

        UnsignedT result{};

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) * 8; i += chunk_bits) {
            result |= static_cast<T>(this->chunks[i / chunk_bits]) << i;
        }

        return negative ? -static_cast<T>(result) : static_cast<T>(result);
    }

    explicit operator std::string() const;

    /// @brief Get the absolute value of the number.
    [[nodiscard]] auto abs() const noexcept -> BigInt;

    /// @brief Convert the number to the specified type.
    ///
    /// @param[out] output Result of the conversion.
    /// @return Whether the conversion was successful.
    [[nodiscard]] auto convert(std::string &output) const noexcept -> bool
    {
        try {
            output = static_cast<std::string>(*this);
            return true;
        } catch (std::invalid_argument const &) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// @brief Convert the number to the specified type.
    ///
    /// @tparam T The type to convert the number to.
    /// @param[out] output Result of the conversion.
    /// @return Whether the conversion was successful.
    [[nodiscard]] auto convert(std::integral auto &output) const noexcept -> bool
    {
        try {
            output = static_cast<decltype(output)>(*this);
            return true;
        } catch (std::overflow_error const &) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// @brief Divide two numbers and return the quotient and remainder.
    ///
    /// @param num The dividend.
    /// @param denom The divisor.
    /// @return The quotient and remainder.
    ///
    /// @throw std::domain_error if the divisor is 0.
    [[nodiscard]] static auto div(BigInt const &num, BigInt const &denom) -> std::pair<BigInt, BigInt>;

    /// @brief Raise the number to the specified power.
    ///
    /// @param power The power to raise the number to.
    /// @return The result of the exponentiation.
    ///
    /// @note Only works for non-negative powers.
    /// @note 0^0 returns 1.
    [[nodiscard]] auto pow(size_t power) const noexcept -> BigInt;

    friend std::formatter<BigInt>;
    friend auto operator""_bi(char const *) -> BigInt;

private:
    /// @brief Sign of the number.
    bool negative{false};
    /// @brief Chunks of the number. Stored in little endian.
    DataType chunks;

    /// @brief Supported bases.
    enum class Base : std::uint_fast8_t
    {
        Binary = 2,
        Octal = 8,
        Decimal = 10,
        Hexadecimal = 16
    };

    /// @brief Number of bits in a chunk.
    static constexpr auto chunk_bits = sizeof(ChunkType) * 8;
    /// @brief Maximum value a chunk can store.
    static constexpr ChunkType chunk_max = std::numeric_limits<ChunkType>::max();

    /// @brief Get the number of bits in the number.
    [[nodiscard]] auto bit_count() const -> size_t;

    /// @brief Get the bit at the specified index.
    ///
    /// @param index The index of the bit to get. 0th bit is the least significant bit and the last bit is the most
    ///              significant bit.
    [[nodiscard]] auto get_bit_at(size_t index) const -> bool;

    /// @brief Check if the number is zero.
    [[nodiscard]] auto is_zero() const -> bool;
    /// @brief Remove leading zero chunks from the number.
    void remove_leading_zeroes();

    /// @brief Compare the magnitude of two numbers. Does not evaluate the sign.
    ///
    /// @param rhs The number to compare to.
    /// @return Ordering of the magnitude of the two numbers.
    [[nodiscard]] auto compare_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> std::strong_ordering;

    /// @brief Add the magnitude of lhs and rhs.
    ///
    /// @param rhs The number to add, must be smaller than or equal to lhs.
    /// @return The result of the addition.
    [[nodiscard]] auto add_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;

    /// @brief Subtract the magnitude of rhs from lhs.
    ///
    /// @param rhs The number to subtract, must be smaller than or equal to lhs.
    /// @return The result of the subtraction.
    [[nodiscard]] auto subtract_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt;

    /// @brief Check if character is a valid digit in the given base.
    ///
    /// @param base The base to check the digit in.
    /// @param c The character to check.
    /// @return True if the character is a valid digit in the given base, false otherwise.
    ///
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.
    [[nodiscard]] static auto is_valid_digit(Base base, char c) -> bool;

    /// @brief Convert character to digit in the given base. The character must be a valid digit in the given base.
    ///
    /// @param base The base to convert the character to.
    /// @param c The character to convert.
    /// @return The digit represented by the character.
    ///
    /// @throws std::invalid_argument if the character is not a valid digit in the given base.
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.
    [[nodiscard]] static auto char_to_digit(Base base, char c) -> ChunkType;

    /// @brief Long divide string representation of a number by a divisor.
    ///
    /// @param num The number to divide, must be unsigned.
    /// @param[out] quotient Resulting quotient.
    /// @param base The base of the number.
    /// @param divisor The divisor.
    /// @return The remainder.
    ///
    /// @throws std::invalid_argument if num contains invalid digits for the given base.
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.
    static auto long_divide(std::string_view num, std::string &quotient, Base base, ChunkType divisor) -> ChunkType;

    /// @brief Convert string with power of two base to binary and store it in chunks.
    ///
    /// @param num The number to convert, must be unsigned.
    /// @param base The base of the number.
    ///
    /// @throws std::invalid_argument if num contains invalid digits for the given base.
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, and 16.
    void power_of_two_base_to_binary(std::string_view num, Base base);

    /// @brief Convert decimal base to binary and store it in chunks.
    ///
    /// @param num The number to convert, must be unsigned.
    ///
    /// @throws std::invalid_argument if num contains invalid digits for the given base.
    void decimal_base_to_binary(std::string_view num);

    /// @brief Convert a base to binary and store it in chunks.
    ///
    /// @param num The number to convert, must be unsigned.
    /// @param base The base of the number.
    ///
    /// @throws std::invalid_argument if num contains invalid digits for the given base.
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.
    void base_to_binary(std::string_view num, Base base);

    /// @brief Format the number to a power of two base.
    ///
    /// @param base The base to format the number to.
    /// @param add_prefix Whether to add a base prefix to the formatted number (e.g. 0b for binary).
    /// @param capitalize Whether to capitalize the base prefix (if any) and the digits (for hexadecimal).
    /// @return The formatted number.
    ///
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, and 16.
    [[nodiscard]] auto
    format_to_power_of_two_base(Base base, bool add_prefix = false, bool capitalize = false) const noexcept
      -> std::string;

    /// @brief Format the number to decimal.
    ///
    /// @return The formatted number.
    [[nodiscard]] auto format_to_decimal() const -> std::string;

    /// @brief Format the number to the specified base.
    ///
    /// @param base The base to format the number to.
    /// @param add_prefix Whether to add a base prefix to the formatted number (e.g. 0b for binary).
    /// @param capitalize Whether to capitalize the base prefix (if any) and the digits (for hexadecimal).
    /// @return The formatted number.
    ///
    /// @note Only works for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.
    [[nodiscard]] auto format_to_base(Base base, bool add_prefix = false, bool capitalize = false) const -> std::string;
};
}  // namespace BI

auto operator<<(std::ostream &os, BI::BigInt const &num) -> std::ostream &;
auto operator""_bi(char const *) -> BI::BigInt;

template<>
struct std::formatter<BI::BigInt> : std::formatter<std::string>
{
    using BigInt = BI::BigInt;

    bool add_prefix = false;
    bool capitalize = false;
    BigInt::Base base{BigInt::Base::Decimal};

    constexpr auto parse(std::format_parse_context &ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin())
    {
        auto const *it = ctx.begin();

        if (it == ctx.end() || *it == '}') {
            return it;
        }

        if (*it == '#') {
            add_prefix = true;
            std::advance(it, 1);
        }

        switch (*it) {
        case 'B':
            capitalize = true;
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 'b':
            base = BigInt::Base::Binary;
            break;
        case 'o':
            base = BigInt::Base::Octal;
            break;
        case 'd':
            base = BigInt::Base::Decimal;
            break;
        case 'X':
            capitalize = true;
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 'x':
            base = BigInt::Base::Hexadecimal;
            break;
        default:
            throw std::format_error("Invalid format specifier");
        }

        std::advance(it, 1);

        if (it != ctx.end() && *it != '}') {
            throw std::format_error("Invalid format specifier");
        }

        return it;
    }

    auto format(BigInt const &num, std::format_context &ctx) const
    {
        return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", num.format_to_base(base, add_prefix, capitalize));
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<BI::BigInt::ChunkType>, "ChunkType must be an unsigned integral type");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<BI::BigInt::DataType::value_type, BI::BigInt::ChunkType>, "DataType must store ChunkType");

src/bigint.cpp:
#include "bigint.hpp"

#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>

using namespace BI;
using namespace BI::detail;

using ChunkType = BigInt::ChunkType;
using DataType = BigInt::DataType;

// Avoid having to convert the number to a BigInt over and over again.
static auto const one = BigInt(1);

BigInt::BigInt()
{
    chunks.push_back(0);
}

BigInt::BigInt(std::string_view num)
{
    auto throw_invalid_number = [&num]() {
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::format("Invalid number: \"{}\"", num));
    };

    if (num.empty()) {
        throw_invalid_number();
    }

    negative = num[0] == '-';
    size_t index = negative ? 1z : 0z;
    Base base{Base::Decimal};

    if (num.size() > index + 1 && num[index] == '0') {
        if (std::tolower(num[index + 1]) == 'x') {
            base = Base::Hexadecimal;
            index += 2;
        } else if (std::tolower(num[index + 1]) == 'b') {
            base = Base::Binary;
            index += 2;
        } else {
            base = Base::Octal;
            index += 1;
        }
    }

    if (index >= num.size()) {
        throw_invalid_number();
    }

    // Convert the number to binary and store it in chunks.
    try {
        base_to_binary(num.substr(index), base);
    } catch (std::invalid_argument const &e) {
        throw_invalid_number();
    }

    // Remove leading zeroes.
    remove_leading_zeroes();
}

auto BigInt::operator+() const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator-() const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    BigInt result{*this};
    result.negative = !result.negative;
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator+(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    if (is_zero()) {
        return rhs;
    }

    if (rhs.is_zero()) {
        return *this;
    }

    bool magnitude_greater = compare_magnitude(rhs) == std::strong_ordering::greater;
    BigInt result;

    if (negative == rhs.negative) {
        result = magnitude_greater ? add_magnitude(rhs) : rhs.add_magnitude(*this);
    } else {
        result = magnitude_greater ? subtract_magnitude(rhs) : rhs.subtract_magnitude(*this);
    }

    result.negative = magnitude_greater ? negative : rhs.negative;
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator-(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    if (is_zero()) {
        return -rhs;
    }

    if (rhs.is_zero()) {
        return *this;
    }

    bool magnitude_greater = compare_magnitude(rhs) == std::strong_ordering::greater;
    BigInt result;

    if (negative == rhs.negative) {
        result = magnitude_greater ? subtract_magnitude(rhs) : rhs.subtract_magnitude(*this);
    } else {
        result = magnitude_greater ? add_magnitude(rhs) : rhs.add_magnitude(*this);
    }

    result.negative = magnitude_greater ? negative : !rhs.negative;
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator*(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    if (is_zero() || rhs.is_zero()) {
        return BigInt{};
    }
    if (*this == one) {
        return rhs;
    }
    if (rhs == one) {
        return *this;
    }

    bool const magnitude_greater = compare_magnitude(rhs) == std::strong_ordering::greater;
    BigInt const &larger = magnitude_greater ? *this : rhs;
    BigInt const &smaller = magnitude_greater ? rhs : *this;

    BigInt result{};

    // Iterate through each bit of the smaller number in reverse order.
    // Shift the result by one bit and add the larger number to the result if the bit is set.
    for (size_t i = smaller.bit_count(); i-- > 0;) {
        result <<= 1;

        if (smaller.get_bit_at(i)) {
            result += larger;
        }
    }

    result.negative = negative != rhs.negative;

    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator/(BigInt const &rhs) const -> BigInt
{
    return div(*this, rhs).first;
}

auto BigInt::operator%(BigInt const &rhs) const -> BigInt
{
    return div(*this, rhs).second;
}

auto BigInt::operator<<(size_t rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    if (is_zero() || rhs == 0) {
        return *this;
    }

    BigInt result{*this};
    // Number of whole chunks to shift.
    size_t chunk_shift = rhs / chunk_bits;
    // Number of bits to shift within a chunk.
    size_t bit_shift = rhs % chunk_bits;

    // Add whole chunks of zeroes to the beginning of the number.
    result.chunks.insert(result.chunks.begin(), chunk_shift, 0);

    // Shift the bits within the remaining chunks.
    if (bit_shift != 0) {
        ChunkType carry = 0;

        for (size_t i = chunk_shift; i < result.chunks.size(); ++i) {
            // Get the bits that will be shifted out of the current chunk and store them in carry.
            // Append the carry from the previous chunk to the current chunk.
            ChunkType new_carry = result.chunks[i] >> (chunk_bits - bit_shift);
            result.chunks[i] = (result.chunks[i] << bit_shift) | carry;
            carry = new_carry;
        }

        // If there is a carry left, add it to the end of the number.
        if (carry != 0) {
            result.chunks.push_back(carry);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator>>(size_t rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    if (is_zero() || rhs == 0) {
        return *this;
    }

    BigInt result{*this};
    // Number of whole chunks to shift.
    size_t chunk_shift = rhs / chunk_bits;
    // Number of bits to shift within a chunk.
    size_t bit_shift = rhs % chunk_bits;

    // Shift is larger than the number of bits in the number, return 0.
    if (chunk_shift >= result.chunks.size()) {
        return BigInt{};
    }

    // Erase the whole chunks that will be shifted.
    result.chunks.erase(result.chunks.begin(), std::next(result.chunks.begin(), to_signed(chunk_shift)));

    // Shift the bits within the remaining chunks.
    if (bit_shift != 0) {
        ChunkType carry = 0;

        for (size_t i = result.chunks.size(); i-- > 0;) {
            // Get the bits that will be shifted out of the current chunk and store them in carry.
            // Append the carry from the previous chunk to the current chunk.
            ChunkType new_carry = result.chunks[i] << (chunk_bits - bit_shift);
            result.chunks[i] = (result.chunks[i] >> bit_shift) | carry;
            carry = new_carry;
        }

        // Clear out any leading zero chunks that may have been created.
        result.remove_leading_zeroes();
    }

    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator+=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this + rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator-=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this - rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator*=(BigInt const &rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this * rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator/=(BigInt const &rhs) -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this / rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator%=(BigInt const &rhs) -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this % rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator<<=(size_t rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this << rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator>>=(size_t rhs) noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this = *this >> rhs;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator++() noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this += one;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator--() noexcept -> BigInt &
{
    *this -= one;
    return *this;
}

auto BigInt::operator++(int) noexcept -> BigInt
{
    BigInt result{*this};
    *this += one;
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator--(int) noexcept -> BigInt
{
    BigInt result{*this};
    *this -= one;
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::operator<=>(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> std::strong_ordering
{
    if (this->is_zero() && rhs.is_zero()) {
        return std::strong_ordering::equal;
    }

    if (negative != rhs.negative) {
        return negative ? std::strong_ordering::less : std::strong_ordering::greater;
    }

    return negative ? rhs.compare_magnitude(*this) : compare_magnitude(rhs);
}

auto BigInt::operator==(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> bool
{
    return (*this <=> rhs) == std::strong_ordering::equal;
}

BigInt::operator std::string() const
{
    return format_to_base(Base::Decimal);
}

auto BigInt::abs() const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    BigInt result{*this};
    result.negative = false;
    return result;
}

auto operator<<(std::ostream &os, BigInt const &num) -> std::ostream &
{
    return os << static_cast<std::string>(num);
}

auto operator""_bi(char const *num) -> BigInt
{
    return BigInt{num};
}

auto BigInt::div(BigInt const &num, BigInt const &denom) -> std::pair<BigInt, BigInt>
{
    if (denom.is_zero()) {
        throw std::domain_error("Division by zero");
    }

    if (num.is_zero()) {
        return {BigInt{}, BigInt{}};
    }

    if (num.compare_magnitude(denom) == std::strong_ordering::less) {
        return {BigInt{}, num};
    }

    BigInt quotient{};
    BigInt remainder{num.abs()};

    // Perform long division:
    // 1. Find the largest multiple of the denominator that fits in the current remainder.
    // 2. Subtract the multiple from the remainder.
    // 3. Repeat until the remainder is less than the denominator.
    while (remainder.compare_magnitude(denom) != std::strong_ordering::less) {
        BigInt temp{denom.abs()};
        // Approximate the amount of shifts needed to align the most significant bit of the denominator with the
        // most significant bit of the remainder.
        size_t shift = remainder.bit_count() - temp.bit_count();

        // Align the most significant bit of the denominator with the most significant bit of the remainder.
        temp <<= shift;

        // If the denominator is still greater than the remainder, shift it to the right once.
        // This will guarantee that the denominator is less than the remainder.
        if (temp.compare_magnitude(remainder) == std::strong_ordering::greater) {
            temp >>= 1;
            --shift;
        }

        // Subtract the multiple from the remainder, and add the multiplier to the quotient.
        remainder -= temp;
        quotient += one << shift;
    }

    // For remainder, the sign is always the same as the dividend.
    remainder.negative = num.negative;
    quotient.negative = num.negative != denom.negative;

    return {quotient, remainder};
}

auto BigInt::pow(size_t power) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    // x^0 = 1
    // NOTE: 0^0 also returns 1.
    if (power == 0) {
        return one;
    }

    // x^1 = x
    // 0^x = 0
    // 1^x = 1
    if (power == 1 || is_zero() || *this == one) {
        return *this;
    }

    static constexpr auto mask = static_cast<size_t>(1) << (sizeof(size_t) * 8 - 1);
    auto const power_leading_zeroes = static_cast<size_t>(std::countl_zero(power));
    // Get amount of bits in the power excluding leading zeroes.
    auto const power_bit_count = (sizeof(size_t) * 8) - power_leading_zeroes;

    // Get rid of leading zeroes so that we can iterate through the bits of the power.
    power <<= power_leading_zeroes;

    BigInt result(1);

    // Iterate through the bits of the power, starting from the most significant bit.
    // Square the result in each iteration, and multiply it by the base if the bit is set.
    // After each iteration, left shift the power by 1 to get the next bit.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < power_bit_count; ++i) {
        result *= result;
        if ((power & mask) != 0) {
            result *= *this;
        }

        power <<= 1;
    }

    return result;
}

auto BigInt::bit_count() const -> size_t
{
    return (chunks.size() * chunk_bits) - static_cast<size_t>(std::countl_zero(chunks.back()));
}

auto BigInt::get_bit_at(size_t index) const -> bool
{
    size_t const chunk_index = index / chunk_bits;
    size_t const bit_index = index % chunk_bits;

    // Even though the chunks are stored in little endian, the bits in a chunk are stored in big endian.
    return static_cast<bool>((chunks[chunk_index] >> bit_index) & 1);
}

auto BigInt::is_zero() const -> bool
{
    return chunks.size() == 1 && chunks[0] == 0;
}

void BigInt::remove_leading_zeroes()
{
    while (chunks.size() > 1 && chunks.back() == 0) {
        chunks.pop_back();
    }
}

auto BigInt::compare_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> std::strong_ordering
{
    if (chunks.size() != rhs.chunks.size()) {
        return chunks.size() <=> rhs.chunks.size();
    }

    for (size_t i = chunks.size(); i-- > 0;) {
        if (chunks[i] != rhs.chunks[i]) {
            return chunks[i] <=> rhs.chunks[i];
        }
    }

    return std::strong_ordering::equal;
}

auto BigInt::add_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    assert(compare_magnitude(rhs) != std::strong_ordering::less);

    BigInt result{*this};
    ChunkType carry = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rhs.chunks.size(); ++i) {
        // Check if the current chunk can be added to without overflow.
        if (result.chunks[i] < chunk_max - rhs.chunks[i] - carry) {
            result.chunks[i] += rhs.chunks[i] + carry;
            carry = 0;
        } else {
            // Add with overflow and carry to next chunk.
            result.chunks[i] += rhs.chunks[i] + carry;
            carry = 1;
        }
    }

    // Add carry to the rest of the number.
    if (carry != 0) {
        for (size_t i = rhs.chunks.size(); i < result.chunks.size(); ++i) {
            if (result.chunks[i] == chunk_max) {
                result.chunks[i] = 0;
            } else {
                result.chunks[i] += carry;
                carry = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add carry to the end of the number.
    if (carry != 0) {
        result.chunks.push_back(1);
    }

    return result;
}

auto BigInt::subtract_magnitude(BigInt const &rhs) const noexcept -> BigInt
{
    assert(compare_magnitude(rhs) != std::strong_ordering::less);

    BigInt result{*this};
    ChunkType borrow = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rhs.chunks.size(); ++i) {
        // Check if the current chunk can be subtracted from without underflow.
        if (result.chunks[i] >= rhs.chunks[i] + borrow) {
            result.chunks[i] -= rhs.chunks[i] + borrow;
            borrow = 0;
        } else {
            // Subtract with underflow and borrow from next chunk.
            result.chunks[i] -= rhs.chunks[i] + borrow;
            borrow = 1;
        }
    }

    // Subtract borrow from the rest of the number.
    if (borrow != 0) {
        for (size_t i = rhs.chunks.size(); i < result.chunks.size(); ++i) {
            if (result.chunks[i] == 0) {
                result.chunks[i] = chunk_max;
            } else {
                result.chunks[i] -= borrow;
                borrow = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Borrow cannot be 1 at the end of the number since rhs is smaller or equal.
    assert(borrow == 0);

    // Remove leading zeroes.
    result.remove_leading_zeroes();

    return result;
}

src/string_parser.cpp:
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <format>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

#include "bigint.hpp"

using namespace BI;
using namespace BI::detail;

using ChunkType = BigInt::ChunkType;
using DataType = BigInt::DataType;

// Character representation of all digits
static constexpr std::array digits = {
  '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
};

// Character representation of all digits in lowercase.
static constexpr std::array digits_lowercase = {
  '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
};

static constexpr auto is_power_of_two(std::integral auto num) -> bool
{
    return num != 0 && (num & (num - 1)) == 0;
}

auto BigInt::is_valid_digit(Base base, char c) -> bool
{
    switch (base) {
    case Base::Binary:
        return c == '0' || c == '1';
    case Base::Octal:
        return c >= '0' && c <= '7';
    case Base::Decimal:
        return std::isdigit(c) != 0;
    case Base::Hexadecimal:
        return std::isxdigit(c) != 0;
    }
}

auto BigInt::char_to_digit(Base base, char c) -> ChunkType
{
    if (!is_valid_digit(base, c)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::format("Invalid digit: {}", c));
    }

    switch (base) {
    case Base::Binary:
    case Base::Octal:
    case Base::Decimal:
        return static_cast<ChunkType>(c - '0');
    case Base::Hexadecimal:
        return static_cast<ChunkType>(std::isdigit(c) != 0 ? (c - '0') : (std::tolower(c) - 'a' + 10));
    }
}

auto BigInt::long_divide(std::string_view num, std::string &quotient, Base base, ChunkType divisor) -> ChunkType
{
    // Clear quotient string and reserve space.
    quotient.clear();
    quotient.reserve(num.size());

    // Numeric value of base.
    auto const base_num = std::to_underlying(base);
    ChunkType dividend = 0;

    for (char digit : num) {
        dividend = dividend * base_num + char_to_digit(base, digit);

        // If dividend >= divisor, divide and store the quotient
        if (dividend >= divisor) {
            ChunkType quot = dividend / divisor;
            ChunkType rem = dividend % divisor;

            assert(base_num < digits.size() && quot < base_num);  // Should always be true for valid bases.
            // NOLINTNEXTLINE(cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index)
            quotient += digits[quot];
            dividend = rem;
        } else if (!quotient.empty()) {
            // If dividend is less than divisor and quotient is non-empty, add '0'.
            quotient += '0';
        }
    }

    return dividend;  // Return the remainder (which is the dividend now).
}

void BigInt::power_of_two_base_to_binary(std::string_view num, Base base)
{
    // Numeric value of base. Used for base conversion.
    auto const base_num = std::to_underlying(base);

    if (!is_power_of_two(base_num)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Base must be a power of 2");
    }

    // The number of bits needed to store a digit in the base.
    auto const bits_per_digit = static_cast<size_t>(std::countr_zero(base_num));

    // Clear the chunks vector.
    chunks.clear();

    ChunkType current_chunk{};
    size_t current_chunk_bits = 0;

    for (size_t i = num.size(); i-- > 0;) {
        // Bits that will fit in the current chunk.
        size_t const added_bits = std::min(bits_per_digit, chunk_bits - current_chunk_bits);
        // Bits that won't fit in the current chunk.
        size_t const remaining_bits = bits_per_digit - added_bits;
        // Digit corresponding to the current character.
        ChunkType const digit = char_to_digit(base, num[i]);

        // Digit without the bits that won't fit in the current chunk.
        ChunkType const digit_masked = digit & ((1 << added_bits) - 1);

        // Add the bits corresponding to the digit to the current chunk.
        current_chunk = (digit_masked << current_chunk_bits) | current_chunk;

        // Increment the number of bits in the current chunk.
        current_chunk_bits += added_bits;

        if (current_chunk_bits == chunk_bits) {
            // The current chunk is full, push it to the chunks vector and reset the chunk.
            chunks.push_back(current_chunk);

            // Some bits may remain in the digit, add them to the new chunk.
            current_chunk = remaining_bits > 0 ? (digit >> added_bits) : 0;
            current_chunk_bits = remaining_bits;
        }
    }

    if (current_chunk_bits > 0) {
        // If the last chunk is not full, push it to the chunks vector.
        chunks.push_back(current_chunk);
    }
}

void BigInt::decimal_base_to_binary(std::string_view num)
{
    // Clear the chunks vector.
    chunks.clear();

    // Maximum number that can fit in a half-sized chunk.
    static constexpr auto const half_chunk_bits = chunk_bits / 2;

    // The process:
    // 1. Long divide the number by 2 ^ half_chunk_bits, the remainder will span half of the chunk. Only half of the
    //    chunk is processed at a time to avoid overflow.
    // 2. Every two iterations, push the full chunk to the chunks vector.
    // 3. Repeat until the number is 0.
    bool is_half_chunk = false;
    ChunkType current_chunk{0};
    static auto divisor = static_cast<ChunkType>(1) << half_chunk_bits;
    std::string current_num{num};
    std::string new_num;

    while (!current_num.empty()) {
        // If the previous iteration was the first half of the chunk, the current iteration will be the second half,
        // and vice versa.
        is_half_chunk = !is_half_chunk;

        // Long divide the current number by the divisor and store the remainder.
        // The resulting quotient is stored in the new_num string.
        ChunkType remainder = long_divide(current_num, new_num, Base::Decimal, divisor);

        // Store the remainder in the current chunk.
        if (is_half_chunk) {
            // First half of the chunk, just store the remainder.
            current_chunk = remainder;
        } else {
            // Full chunk, push it to the chunks vector and reset the chunk.
            // The most significant half of the chunk is the remainder from this iteration.
            chunks.push_back((remainder << half_chunk_bits) | current_chunk);
            current_chunk = 0;
        }

        // Swap the current and new num strings to avoid reallocations.
        std::swap(current_num, new_num);
    }

    // If the last chunk is not full, push it to the chunks vector.
    if (is_half_chunk) {
        chunks.push_back(current_chunk);
    }
}

void BigInt::base_to_binary(std::string_view num, Base base)
{
    if (is_power_of_two(std::to_underlying(base))) {
        power_of_two_base_to_binary(num, base);
    } else {
        assert(base == Base::Decimal);
        decimal_base_to_binary(num);
    }
}

auto BigInt::format_to_power_of_two_base(Base base, bool add_prefix, bool capitalize) const noexcept -> std::string
{
    // Amount of bits that fit in a single digit of the specified base.
    auto const digit_bits = static_cast<ChunkType>(std::countr_zero(std::to_underlying(base)));
    size_t bit_count = this->bit_count();
    std::string result;
    // Reserve enough space for the result.
    result.reserve((bit_count / digit_bits) + 1 + (add_prefix ? 2 : 0));

    // Iterate through chunks of digit_bits bits and convert them to the specified base.
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < bit_count) {
        // Number of bits to extract from the current chunk.
        size_t const extracted_bits = std::min(digit_bits, bit_count - i);

        ChunkType digit = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < extracted_bits; ++j) {
            digit |= static_cast<ChunkType>(get_bit_at(i + j)) << j;
        }

        // NOLINTNEXTLINE(cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index)
        result += capitalize ? digits[digit] : digits_lowercase[digit];

        i += extracted_bits;
    }

    // Reverse the result string to make it MSB first.
    std::ranges::reverse(result);

    if (result.empty()) {
        result = "0";
    }

    std::string prefix;

    if (add_prefix) {
        switch (base) {
        case Base::Binary:
            prefix = capitalize ? "0B" : "0b";
            break;
        case Base::Octal:
            prefix = "0";
            break;
        case Base::Hexadecimal:
            prefix = capitalize ? "0X" : "0x";
            break;
        case Base::Decimal:
            assert(false);  // Should never happen.
        }
    }

    result.insert(0, prefix);
    return result;
}

auto BigInt::format_to_decimal() const -> std::string
{
    BigInt quotient{*this};
    BigInt remainder;
    static auto const ten = BigInt(10);
    static auto const log2_10 = std::log2(10);
    std::string result;
    // Reserve enough space for the result.
    result.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(std::ceil(static_cast<long double>(quotient.bit_count()) / log2_10) + 1));

    // Keep dividing modulo 10 and store the remainder in a string.
    while (!quotient.is_zero()) {
        std::tie(quotient, remainder) = div(quotient, ten);
        // Append the remainder to the result string.
        // NOLINTNEXTLINE(cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index)
        result += digits[remainder.chunks[0]];
    }

    std::ranges::reverse(result);
    return result.empty() ? "0" : result;
}

auto BigInt::format_to_base(Base base, bool add_prefix, bool capitalize) const -> std::string
{
    if (is_zero()) {
        return "0";
    }
    if (negative) {
        return "-" + (-(*this)).format_to_base(base, add_prefix, capitalize);
    }
    if (is_power_of_two(std::to_underlying(base))) {
        return format_to_power_of_two_base(base, add_prefix, capitalize);
    }
    assert(base == Base::Decimal);
    return format_to_decimal();
}

src/utils.hpp:
#pragma once

#include <limits>
#include <source_location>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

namespace BI::detail
{
template<typename T>
static constexpr auto to_unsigned(T const &num) -> std::make_unsigned_t<T>
{
    if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T>) {
        return num;
    } else {
        if (num < 0) {
            throw std::underflow_error("Number is negative and cannot be converted to an unsigned type");
        }
        return static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(num);
    }
}

template<typename T>
static constexpr auto to_signed(T const &num) -> std::make_signed_t<T>
{
    if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T>) {
        return num;
    } else {
        if (num > std::numeric_limits<std::make_signed_t<T>>::max()) {
            throw std::overflow_error("Number is too large to be converted to a signed type");
        }
        return static_cast<std::make_signed_t<T>>(num);
    }
}

/// @brief Get the raw function name of a function with the type as a template parameter.
template<typename T>
constexpr auto type_to_string_raw() -> std::string_view
{
    return std::source_location::current().function_name();
}

/// @brief Raw function name of long double type, used to find the length of the prefix and suffix of the raw string.
constexpr std::string_view long_double_raw_string = type_to_string_raw<long double>();
constexpr std::string_view long_double_string = "long double";

template<std::size_t... Idxs>
constexpr auto substring_as_array(std::string_view str, std::index_sequence<Idxs...> /*unused*/)
{
    return std::array{str[Idxs]...};
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto type_name_array()
{
    // Find prefix and suffix of every raw string using known type, by searching for the known type in the raw string.
    static constexpr auto prefix_len = long_double_raw_string.find(long_double_string);
    static constexpr auto suffix_len = long_double_raw_string.size() - prefix_len - long_double_string.size();

    constexpr std::string_view type_raw_string = type_to_string_raw<T>();
    constexpr auto start = prefix_len;
    constexpr auto end = type_raw_string.size() - suffix_len;

    static_assert(start < end);

    constexpr auto name = type_raw_string.substr(start, (end - start));

    // Convert the substring to a std::array so it can be used in a constexpr context.
    return substring_as_array(name, std::make_index_sequence<name.size()>{});
};

template<typename T>
struct type_name_holder
{
    static constexpr auto value = type_name_array<T>();
};

/// @brief Get the name of a type as a string.
///
/// @tparam T The type to get the name of.
/// @return The name of the type.
///
/// @see https://rodusek.com/posts/2021/03/09/getting-an-unmangled-type-name-at-compile-time/
template<typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() -> std::string_view
{
    constexpr auto &value = type_name_holder<T>::value;
    return std::string_view(value.data(), value.size());
}
}  // namespace BI::detail
```



the magnitude being stored as a std::deque of chunks

It's a valid option, but how often is there an insertion or deletion at the front? operator<< inserts at the front, but it doesn't have to, it could insert extra space in the back and then work back-to-front to shift the bits.

Each chunk is an integer of type std::uint_fast32_t.

A common pitfall is picking an extremely small chunk size, such as a decimal digit or a byte. You have avoided that pitfall, std::uint_fast32_t is fine, although more complicated than picking a fixed size. By the way the "chunks" of a bigint are often called "limbs" (I don't know why, but that's common terminology).
Algorithms
You can do better than the shift-and-add algorithm for multiplication using the classic grade school multiplication algorithm. I realize you're dealing with uint_fast32_t but to simplify for exposition purposes, if you have two 32-bit chunks you can cast them to 64-bit and multiply them to get the full product. Then take the low 32 bits and high 32 bits of that product separately, and add them into the result (I'm skipping some details here). This is not just hiding the shift-and-add business under a layer of abstraction, most processors today have a built-in multiplication that is very fast, not at all comparable to a shift-and-add loop.
There are more elaborate integer multiplication algorithms that scale better to larger numbers, such as Karatsuba multiplication, Toom-Cook, etc. These don't replace the simple grade-school multiplication algorithm, they only "kick in" for sufficiently large integers.
For division, there is Knuths classic algorithm D for multi-word division, you don't have to do it bit-by-bit (this too doesn't just hide the bit-by-bit business under a layer of abstraction, processors these days can have pretty fast dividers which you can make use of this way). By the way you can get the quotient and remainder at the same time more efficiently than each separately, and various algorithms need both of them at the same time. Similar to multiplication there are also more elaborate algorithms for division, that also only kick in past a certain size.
The algorithm for BigInt::pow is fine, it's a bit simpler to use the exponent from the least significant bit first though, then you don't need all that counting and shifting before the loop. You could add a modPow (modular exponentiation) also, that's typically a separate built-in operation from pow because separate exponentiation followed by modular reduction would often result in an unacceptably large intermediate result.
Conversion to a decimal string can perhaps surprisingly use a somewhat more efficient algorithm as well. That probably doesn't matter as much, but still, there are things you could do if you want. There are two main tricks that I know of:

Recursively "halve" the bigint by div-rem'ing it by large powers of ten that are near the square root of the bigint (estimate it based on bit-length, don't compute actual square roots). Finding/creating the appropriate power of 10 and then "halving" a bigint that way is a little bit more expensive than dividing by 10, but this very quickly reduces the size so that subsequent operations are much faster. Repeatedly dividing by 10 (or a slightly higher power of ten, see point 2) doesn't work that way, that way the bigint shrinks only slowly. Be careful with the string lengths of the "halves", the values themselves don't implicitly encode their length. For example after splitting 100001 down the middle, the halves have values 100 and 1, combining them into "1001" is obviously bad.
Div-rem by a larger power of 10 that still fits in an integer, say 109, then convert the "piece" of the bigint that was "broken off" that way to decimal (including leading zeroes) using cheap normal integer arithmetic instead of expensive bigint arithmetic.


How would the grade-school multiplication algorithm work for two 64-bit chunks? Or are you suggesting that I used a fixed size of 32 for the chunks

@Famiu either way works, if chunks can be 64-bit (or in general larger than 32-bit I suppose, hypothetically some strange size) you can still split them during the multiplication. It's a bit of extra hassle, but that lets chunks be larger in other contexts (addition and such).

Also do you have any opinion on the string to BigInt conversion algorithm used? (The decimal_base_to_binary() function). I came up with that one entirely on my own so I'm curious how efficient that is.

@Famiu oh right I skipped over that, doing division on strings is probably not great. You could do the old result = result * 10 + (digit - '0') basically, starting at the most significant digit, or get more fancy with parsing chunks of 9 digits to an int

Also I used std::deque is because insertions in general are cheaper with a deque than a vector, regardless of whether it's in the back or in the front. Please correct me if that's incorrect.

I think the reason the components are called limbs is because they are the next level up from digits which are our fingers and toes.

@Famiu maybe, I wouldn't really put it that way, more like: the worst case of an individual push_back is not as bad as it can be for a vector. Which is fine, maybe that's what we need here, I'm not sure. But overall deque usually ends up disappointing me.

@TobySpeight that makes a lot of sense actually.

@user555045 I actually added benchmarks and you were right, std::vector is significantly faster. Also noticed that uint_fast32_t (which is 64 bits on my machine) is actually significantly faster than uint32_t. I'm not sure whether that's due to the actual speed of the type, or because the amount of chunks is reduced

@Famiu probably the reduced chunk count, at least on the popular kinds of 64-bit CPU (x64 and 64-bit ARM) there is no penalty for 32-bit arithmetic per se
